# Create a Windows XP Scheduled Task to run at the logon of each user

Tags: windows, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

On Windows Vista onwards it's possible to configure a scheduled task to run at the logon of every user by setting the schedule to "At Logon" and the user account to be a group of users (E.g., Everyone).

I'm now trying to replicate this behaviour on an XP machine, but I'm having absolutely no luck. I've tried NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, Administrators, Everyone but each of these prevents my task from launching.

For the time being, I'm testing by opening notepad.exe.

Is this possible pre-Vista?

Comment: If you are trying to run a specified program and not a scheduled task you can use `GPEdit.msc` in Windows XP it's supported from Windows 2000

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui While a possible solution, I'd like something a little neater and something that can be programmatically configured

Comment: I was trying with a scheduled task, and I confirm your phenomenon, I am using XP SP3 and it fails to launch my task.